# django form field regex validation for alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form, which contains a password field, I want to validate the field that it must contain a combination of alphabets and numbers.

```
class AuthorizationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=7)
```

I am validating the password field like this:

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]+$', password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password should be a combination of Alphabets and Numbers")
```

This piece of code isn't working for me, it allows `abcdefghij` or `123456789` or `abcd123456`, where as I just want to allow `abcd123456`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex isn't really necessary, you can simply use string functions to do this:

```
import string

def validate(password):
    letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
    digits = set(string.digits)
    pwd = set(password)
    return not (pwd.isdisjoint(letters) or pwd.isdisjoint(digits))

print(validate('123123'))    # False
print(validate('asdfsdf'))   # False
print(validate('12312sfdf')) # True
```

Answer (score 34):

You can using `RegexValidator` that is a [django builtin validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#built-in-validators).

Try below code:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class AuthorizationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        min_length=7,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                '^(\w+\d+|\d+\w+)+$',
                message="Password should be a combination of Alphabets and Numbers"
            )
        ]
    )
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The problem is with the regex, not with the way it's called.

Comment: This problem resolved by this way, and **regex** technique used in different way. this way is highest standard as original @MHS way and is pythonic way.